# how do you tell what a python module is named, and therefore should be imported as on windows?

Tags: python, module, naming-conventions, libraries

I've installed many third party libraries on my windows machine, however I want to know **How do you know what name to import them as in your scripts?**

The scripts are from [windows python binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

For example I have installed and often use beautifulsoup.

When I import it as "import BeautifulSoup" it is not recognised, but when someone told me to type "from bs4 import beautifulsoup" it worked.

Therefore there are some other modules I have installed, e.g. pyQt4 which is installed to C/python27/scripts/ (when I run the installer it says it's already installed there).

How do I know what name I should be importing PyQt4?

And why didn't just "import BeautifulSoup" work?

I.e. do I have to type "from Py4 import ....." Or maybe it's called py4?

Comment: Google the package and you'll find the docs.

Comment: Documentation, documentation, documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: Look at the module's docs for info. You also may want to check`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` for folder names.
Answer 2: Bs4 is the 'main module'. beautifulsoup is a sub-class or sub-module. Kind of like doing `from time import sleep`. That would mean you could only use `time.sleep()`, not anything else in the `time` module.